# How do I declare an async function?

Tags: c++, stdasync

I am new to threads and async functions and I am trying use async function to return information from the function below:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > calculatingSlices(SquareMatrix A, std::vector<std::vector<int> > slices)
```

and I am doing this using the following code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> slices;
std::vector<std:future<std::vector<int>>> results;
for(int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++){
    results.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, calculatingSlices, A, slices))
}
```

I am getting this error though:

```
error: attempt to use a deleted function
```

So I guess my initial question is how do you declare an async function?

I also have a few questions about how async functions work. 
If you're declaring a number of async functions in a loop, like I have done above, will these all run simultaneously? or will they run one at a time as it progresses through the loop?

If they run one at a time, what would be a better way to run this function simultaneously amongst a varying number of threads?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please post full message errors. The error you posted gives no hint whatsoever to the error.
2. Please post compilable and fully reproducible [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
3. The compilation error by [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/-cIvml) is pretty clear:

```
<source>:14:87: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::future<std::vector<int> >
>::push_back(std::future<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >)'

         results.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, calculatingSlices, A, slices))
```

As the return value of `calculatingSlices` is `vector<vector>`, you want to store `vector<future<vector<vector>>>` not `vector<future<vector>>>`. The function returns a 2d vector, not 1d.

So change:

```
std::vector<std:future<std::vector<int>>> results;
```

into

```
std::vector<std::future<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>> results;
```